# how to keep springboot default log when using logback-spring.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot

the springboot default log is something like following:

```
2020-04-06 19:34:11.323  INFO 19308 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-06 19:34:11.323  INFO 19308 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-04-06 19:34:11.424  INFO 19308 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-06 19:34:11.424  INFO 19308 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initializ
```

And I wrote a logback-spring.xml for setting some logger and appender for my application. However, when the logback-spring.xml exists in "resources" directory, the springboot default log will disappear. And there is only a `<configuration>` without any subelement in logback-spring.xml.

I have read the part of springboot document which is about logging and got the [file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml). But I don't know how to use it...I tried to copy the element `<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN  ...` into my logback-spring.xml and using it as the formatter of my appender, then attaching the appender to `<root>`. But it can't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the base configuration in your logback-spring.xm file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<configuration scan="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="your.application.package" level="DEBUG"/>  
</configuration>
```